# How create Rowlist where item width is based on text,

Tags: roku, brightscript

I need to create rowlist with text, where the item width is based on the item text
Please check attached images for reference,

[Here need to change "**Breaking new**" text item width as per text length.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SUnUQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

here the XML component for image :

```
<PosterGrid 
      id = "ChannelPosterGrid" 
      translation = "[ 10 , 10 ]"      
      caption1NumLines = "2" 
      caption2NumLines = "2"
      numColumns="4"
      numRows="6"
      focusBitmapUri="pkg:/images/imagegrid.png"
      itemSpacing = "[ 20, 20 ]" />
```

First, init() function to find id in postergrid
`m.top.grid = m.top.findNode("ChannelPosterGrid")`

Brightscript code for show rawlist :

```
sub showpostergrid()
? " I am in showpostergrid() "
  m.top.grid.content = m.readPosterGridTask.content
' m.top.grid.FHDPosterUrl = m.readPosterGridTask.hdposterurl
end sub
```

Brightscript code for read rawlist :

```
sub readpostergrid()

'? "I am in readpostergrid() " m.top.gridcontenturi

  'the code of roPosterGrid
  m.ChannelPosterGrid = m.top.FindNode("ChannelPosterGrid")
  m.readPosterGridTask = createObject("roSGNode", "XmlReader")
' screen = createobject("roParagraphScreen")
' m.readPosterGridTask.backgroundColor = "008000"
  m.readPosterGridTask.contenturi = m.top.gridcontenturi
  m.readPosterGridTask.observeField("content", "showpostergrid")
' m.readPosterGridTask.contenturi = "pkg:/xml/AllChannel.xml"
' m.readPosterGridTask.contenturi = "http://api.delvenetworks.com/rest/organizations/59021fabe3b645968e382ac726cd6c7b/channels/1cfd09ab38e54f48be8498e0239f5c83/media.rss" 'Roku rss XML
  m.readPosterGridTask.color = "008000"
' screen.AddParagraph("Hello Nikunj")
  m.readPosterGridTask.control = "RUN"
end sub
```

Comment: Sorry, This above example not a RowList. It's PanelSet. Latest News Programmer on TV. It's a LabelPanel and Breaking News Also a LabelPanel. Here Both are interacting with child LabelPanel. using a RowList you can manage only a Single Row. Multiple Row managed with RowList. But Here some limitations. I tried But not maintain a Focus. So Better option this.